# How to concatenate a list and a dataframe to create a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

I am trying to concatenate a list and a dataframe in Python, by doing so I receive the error below:

`error cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'list'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid`.

The first df looks like this:

```
assets =  ['ABN.AS','ACCEL.AS','ADYEN.AS','AGN.AS']
Type(assets)= list
```

The second df looks like this:

```
Curr=    
            ABN.AS  ACCEL.AS    ADYEN.AS    AGN.AS  Idx
        1   EUR     EUR         EUR         EUR     currency
        
 type(curr)=pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

Above, the number 1 is just redundant information, it automatically appears if I run the code to scrape the currency of the ticker. Python does not see the number 1 as separate column (while running `print(curr)`

I have removed the last column, which is not relevant.

```
curr = curr.drop(['idx'],axis =1)
```

I can't delete the header row, I tried this: `curr.columns = range(curr.shape[1])`
The df looks like this now, I can't remove the annoying 2, which is redundant.

```
    0   1   2   3   4       
2   EUR EUR EUR EUR EUR
```

The goal is to create a new df (dictionary), which have to look like this:

```
assets_result={'ABN.AS':'EUR','ACCEL.AS':'EUR','ADYEN.AS':'EUR','AGN.AS':'EUR'}
Type(assets_result)= dict
```

I have tried to do this, which resulted in the above mentioned error:

```
result = pd.concat([assets, curr])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
curr.drop(['idx'], axis=1).iloc[0].to_dict()
```

or:

```
curr[assets].iloc[0].to_dict()
```